# Loop through command buttons in range depending on cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I have a number of command buttons in Column O which I would like to conditionally display depending on whether a "Y" is entered into the corresponding cell in Column R.

The best and most efficient way to tackle it is with a counter.

The below doesn't work, but I hope the intention is clear. I've played around with a few techniques, but I'm no expert.

```
For Each CommandButton In Range("O5:O34")

For counter = 1 To 30

If Range("R" & 4 + counter) = "Y" Then
    CommandButton & counter.Visible = True
Else
    CommandButton & counter.Visible = False
End If

Next counter

Next CommandButton
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
Dim c as Range, i as Long
i = 1
For Each c In activesheet.Range("R5:R34")
    activesheet.shapes("CommandButton" & i).visible = (c.Value = "Y")
    i = i + 1
Next c
```

Assuming your commandbuttons are all named accordingly

Comment: 'The item with the specified name wasn't found'... Shortening it to just two buttons, named 'CommandButton1' and 'CommandButton2'.

Comment: I should have spotted that. Thanks.

Comment: Had a tinker, and I've found the following applies for the enabled property, if anyone needs to do the same:

`ActiveSheet.Shapes("CommandButton" & j).OLEFormat.Object.Enabled = (c.Value > 0)`